# TestNG @BerforeMethod runs in different browser than the test

Tags: testng

I'd like to open the page under test in a method annotated with @BeforeMethod and then use this browser instance for the test but now setUp runs in one browser and for the test TestNG opens a new browser instance. How can I solve this?
I run the xml from IntelliJ:

```
<suite name="all" verbose="1">
<test name="AllTests" preserve-order="true" time-out="7200000">
    <classes>
        <class name="test.ProjectCreationTests">
            <methods>
                <include name="testNewProject" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

I also tried to run the test from IntelliJ by method and in that case it works as I expected, the browser opened by setup get used by the test.

**Update1:**
I use Selenide so I don't have to initialize driver. I think there is nothing special in my test and I cannot share the whole, sorry. baseURL is defined in a @BeforeClass method.

```
@Test
public void testNewProject() {
    createProjectPage.tickProjectType(CreateProjectPage.ProjectTypeOptions.NEW_PROJECT);
    createProjectPage.clickOnNext();
    ...

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
    createProjectPage = open("/createProject.spr", CreateProjectPage.class);

}
```

Comment: where is your driver initialisation code? Please share that, as well as the method `testNewProject` and your `@BeforeMethod`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. @BeforeMethod, @AfterMethod etc. runs in different thread when timeOut defined. Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/8XYt-El2_JU